# How to get the values of an Bootstrap Toggle Button?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get the value '0' and '1' out of my toggle button?
The value one or zero will be sent to the order.inc.php page when the button is pressed.

Order.php page:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <form method="post" action="includes/edit-orderstatus.inc.php">
        <td><input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-off="Shipped" data-on="Pending" data-offstyle="success" id="statusOrder" name="statusOrder" data-onstyle="danger" value="1"></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="orderID" id="orderID" value="<?php echo ($datas[$i]['ID']);?>">
        <td><button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit" name="orderstatus-submit">Submit</button></td>
    </form>
</div>
```

Order.inc.php page

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['orderstatus-submit'])){

        require('../php/connection.php');
        $toogleButtonValue = (int)(isset($_POST['statusOrder']) && $_POST['statusOrder'] == 1);

        echo $toogleButtonValue;

}
```

Comment: The checkbox doesn't send data to the server if not checked. So remove checked attribute, so the toggle is set to off, make sure to give to data-off and data-on the right values, andd once in you check it manually, it will send On to the server.

Comment: if your check-box is checked then value `1` will be send if its not checked then no value will be send.So, you can just check `if(isset($_POST['statusOrder'])){ $value =1;}else{ $value = 0 ;}` and then just `echo $value` you will get required value.

Answer (score 1):

You must set value attribute of checkbox, i.e. `value="1"`.

It returns `1` if any value was sent or `0` otherwise.

```
$toogleButtonValue = (int)(isset($_POST['statusOrder']) && $_POST['statusOrder'] == 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tajni. The output is always 0. Which means data is not sended in both toggle cases.

Comment: Updated answer. You must set `value` of checkbox.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I updated my version above with your comments, however it is still showing 0 when submitting both toggle values.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can test and if still not working can you print `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: array(2) {
  ["orderID"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["orderstatus-submit"]=>
  string(0) ""
}

Comment: In the var-dump orderstatus-stubmit in there? Isnt that the wrong variable?

Comment: I tried to $_POST['statusOrder']. Output: Notice: Undefined index: statusOrder

Comment: If check I want to send the data @Tajni

Comment: Try to send with checked and unchecked toggle. And also change `<button` to `<input`.